# Hot Reload doesn't reload libraries in VScode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I run the demo app through 'Run Without Debugging' (Ctrl+F5) and try to hot reload it, hot reload doesn't work. Every time I try to hot reload, I see this:

```
Reloaded 0 of 529 libraries in 244ms.
Reloaded 0 of 529 libraries in 117ms.
Reloaded 0 of 529 libraries in 123ms.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you making any changes between reloads? If nothing changes in the apps files then they'll be nothing to reload :)

Comment: Yes, I change the primary colour in ThemeData()

Comment: It turned out that Hot reload works perfectly if I use Ctrl+S instead of the lightning button

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Hot reload works perfectly if you use Ctrl+S instead of the lightning button. Try this.